# File not uploading in flask

Tags: python, flask

main.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == "POST":
        userFile = request.files('uFile')
        fileName = secure_filename(userFile.filename)
        userFile.save(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], fileName))
        return "Uploaded"
```

index.html

```
 <form action="/" method="POST">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="formFile" class="form-label"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="uFile" name="uFile">
            </div>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
File "C:\Users\Shakti Ranjan Debata\Desktop\Minimal\ImageFilter\main.py", line 15, in hello_world
userFile = request.files('uFile')
```

Comment: Can you post your full main.py file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use brackets for the request:

```
        userFile = request.files['uFile']
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with your main.py, not your index.html. Flask needs you to use square brackets [] when handling requests. In main.py replace that route with:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
  if request.method == "POST":
    userFile = request.files['uFile']
    fileName = secure_filename(userFile.filename)
    userFile.save(path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], fileName))
    return "Uploaded"
```

That's all, and your issues should be solved. Flask doesn't allow you to use ordinary brackets to handle requests. I hope this helps, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Change "(" ")" to square brackets. In python dict accessing is done through square brackets.